# Which service or application is responsible for Mission Control?

Tags: macos, mission-control

From time to time I get my OS X bugging up like this:

[image: Buggy Mission Control]

I tried restarting Finder, Dock or WindowServer processes to no avail. Has anyone encountered this? May be there is a service or an app that I can relaunch to fix this? So far only restart helped. I didn't try the login/logout flow, but I'm pretty sure it would work too. So I wanted to know if there is a way to fix this while logged in.

Answer (score 1):

The application responsible for Mission Control should be Dock.

Take a look at this article. [Restart Mission Control in OS X Lion](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/23/restart-mission-control-in-os-x-lion/)

Answer (score 1):

The [windowserver](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/QuartzDisplayServicesConceptual/Articles/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004226-SW1) handles all mission control animations and knowing which windows are visible at any one time for the screen buffers that are active. From a design standpoint - this process implements the Quartz Display Services.

You might not want to just kill that process since that basically logs you out, but it might be interesting to know if the issue you report persists over sessions or is more of an inadvertent triggering of the mission control view or is really a bug in the tracking so that your presentation layer things that this is really what should be drawn on your main screen currently.